# jquery: get the coordinates (x, y) of the focus (not mouse cursor) in input (textarea etc)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cursor, focus

How to get pixels coordinates ({x,y} relative to the left top window coordinates) of focus in the input (textarea etc)?
I want to display a pop-up window in the place where the focus is in the text.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of javascript's function `onfocus`. Each text input you wish to be enabled for this function would have an `onfocus` function that would set a global variable of its coordinates.
Here's a code sample of this

```
var focusX = null;
var focusY = null;
function setFocus(event){
    let coords = event.path[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    focusX = coords.x;
    focusY = coords.y;
}
document.getElementById("myTextarea").onfocus = setFocus;
```

And the HTML code for this specific example:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <textarea id="myTextarea"></textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: no!
onfocus does not work, I need so that I can at any time know the coordinates of the flashing cursor in the textarea